# HQL and one-to-many queries

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have Hibernate domain objects that looks like this:

```
   class Player {
      List<Item> inventory;
   }

   class Item {
      List<Enchantment> enchantments;
   }

   class Enchantment {
      boolean isSuperiorEnchantment;
   }
```

I need to construct an HQL query that returns to me a list of all players that have at least one item with an enchantment on it that has the `isSuperiorEnchantment` flag set.  I can't for the life of me figure out a way to express this in HQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming the appropriate mappings on all of the above, the query you're looking for is:

```
select p
from Player as p
  left join p.inventory as i
  left join i.enchantments as e
where e.isSuperiorEnchantment = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  I had to remember to add a "select p" to the front of it, but otherwise it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: I'm just learning HQL, but in regular SQL this wouldn't work -- the left join would mean you'll get Player results even if there are no matching records in Inventory and Enchantments.  (I'll keep digging for clarification on this... I have a suspicion "left join" means something different in HQL, or this query wouldn't be much use).

Comment: @RobWhelan The above query would work (with appropriate adjustments to syntax, of course) just fine in regular SQL due to `e.isSuperiorEnchantment = 1` condition which would not be satisfied for Players without Enchantments since `isSuperiorEnchantment` would be returned as null.

Comment: @ChssPly76 Ah, you're right -- I was reading that as an "on" clause rather than the regular "where".  Though it's still a strange way to construct a query -- normally you'd just use plain old inner joins, and the query optimizer could ignore all of the Player rows missing Inventory or Enchantments before even hitting the filter.