# hibernate query for fetching entity on multiple collection values

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to fetch an entity that contains two matching collection entities.

```
public class A {
    long id;
    Set<B> bs;
}

public class B {
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

If I have the following table data

```
Table A
ID     Name 
1      pluto
2      earth
3      mars

Table B
ID     A_ID     NAME     VALUE
1       1       abc       123
2       1       xyz       789
3       2       abc       456
4       2       xyz       789
5       3       abc       123
```

I want to fetch all "A's" that has at least 1 B with name='abc' and value='123' AND 1 B with name='xyz' and value='789'.  I want only the A named 'pluto' in this example as 'earth' doesn't have the correct value for "abc" and mars is missing "xyz".

Do I have to use a subselect to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use a one-to-many association between A and B...

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-12m

... afterwards you can find plenty of examples of querying that association, e.g....

[HQL and one-to-many queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167630/hql-and-one-to-many-queries)

Comment: Yes....I have the entities mapped fine and am using hibernate to query ok.  My new requirement is this additional query.  There are examples in "Java Persistence with Hibernate" and hibernate ref docs that show how to select an "A" entity given a value of a "B" entity in the collection - but none that cover how to handle looking for an "A" with two different "B"s that have specific values.

Comment: Although not exact, the bottom link is a very similar question. If you tweak that answer a bit you'll find your solution. Probably something like "select a from A as a left join a.bs as b where b.name='abc' and b.value='123'".

Comment: Your case is easy to understand - but I need the case where I'm selecting A with b.name='abc' AND a different b.name='xyz' - and only those A's.