# Null problem with list of objects in HQL query response

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I post this here because I'm facing a problem and I can't find a way to resolve it. 
I already looked for solutions all over the place but didn't find any that unstucked me.

For my project I'm using hibernate and Spring Boot.

I have have the following classes:

**A.java**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "a")
@Data
public class A implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "audit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AAD> aADs;
   ...
}
```

**AAD.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_a_d")
@Data
public class AAD implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_id")
    private A a;
}
```

**B.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Data
public class B implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "price")
    private Double price;
    ...
}
```

When i try to Request some info in my `ARepositoryImpl` without any filter as follow

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.aADs aad LEFT JOIN aad.b b");
Query queryPhase1 = getEntityManager().createQuery(request.toString());
finalResult = queryPhase1.getResultList();
```

I have my results as expected with all the informations:

```
 - 0 = {A@18952}
       _ id = {Long@19678} 2
         ...
       _ aADs = {PersistentBag@1978} size = 2
           - 0 = {B@12346}
           - 1 = {B@25463}
                _ id = {Long@123547} 1
                  ...
                _ price = {Double@125487} 17.0
 - 1 = {A@5478}
    ...
 - 2 = {A@1234}
    ...
```

But as soon as i add a filter i have a null result. That's the moment i totally lost it :(

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.aADs aad LEFT JOIN aad.b b WHERE b.price=17.0"); 
// I saw in the previous result that a B.price was equals to 17.0 so i try to filter on it so i obtain only my A objects which have a B.price = 17.0
// I should at least obtain {A@18952} in the reuslt of this query if i look my previous result
    Query queryPhase1 = getEntityManager().createQuery(request.toString());
    finalResult = queryPhase1.getResultList();
```

Moreover their is no error just an Empty list at the end of the query. I tried to reformat my query and to search directly on aad (without using a left join) but i have a dereference error when i try this.

Someone with a tip, or an answer to unblocked me would really be a life savior because i will soon be out of hair :/

Thanks for your time and sorry for the long post, 
Here, have this [sweet potato kiss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUHOa.jpg)

P.S.: I don't think this is a duplicate of another post because I browsed for it all afternoon, if I'm wrong I would really appreciate your link guys!

---

**EDIT**

I'm gonna try to get my query from scratch using a workaround to get my infos, i hope this will work. I will filter first on `B` and get my ID's back, then i will search for my `AAD` objects (and so my `A` objects) thanks to those ids.

---

**EDIT 2**

My work-around is actually getting the infos as expected, i will keep this in line as long as i dont find any fix to the previous case. If someone know something please tell me i would greatly appreciate !

Comment: Try testing with something like `WHERE  b.price>16.0`, what does that give you?

Comment: Try that sql directly in db client. If it works let us know.

Comment: Have you tried SQL directly? If so, let us know and also please log SQL created by Hibernate and post it too.

Comment: That is not sql, but hql, not the same

Comment: @Palencar Try to filter by some other property to test if it works. Take something from `a` object for test

Comment: @Niver if i filter with a property if A the request works fine ans the results are the one expected.

Comment: @Leandro Lima, the request in SQL works perfectly, i think the problem ATM IS situated with the use of a list in hql and so he can't reach the properties inside this list for the filter. :/ but if cannot find how to work around this problem

Comment: @xtratic when i try to look for >16 i keep getting a null result. Still no error nor expected results

Comment: @Palencar could you update the question with the log showing what SQL Hibernate created to you?

Comment: @Palencar About use of list in HQL, this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167630/hql-and-one-to-many-queries shows a case that work.

Comment: @LeandroLima I cant find the querie hql generated even in my logs , i will try to dig this up if i can. 
Thanks for the post unfortunatly the solution evoqued here is already in use but it's still not working. :/

Comment: @Palencar To try help you better I need to reproduce your code. For the moment the relationship between A and AAD caught my attention. You have, in the A side a oneToMany and in the AAD side OneToOne. Is it purposiful?

Comment: @Palencar I have reproduced your code and I believe that the problem resides on something you didn't show us. Please update your question with "audit" field on AAD class.